# Verify if email is used for paypal

Tags: email, paypal, verify

i need to verify if certain email is already assigned to paypal account, i know the https://www.paypal.com/us/verified/pal= is not restricted only to partnered accounts so this option won't work for me.

It might be a simple work around, just to check if the provided email is an existing paypal account

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why Paypal would give out that information.

It could allow fraudsters to send email posing as Paypal to Paypal customers with intention to commit fraud, knowing for sure that they are registered users.

It would seem allowing 'user enumeration' is that way would benefit the fraudsters and would cost them nothing, because besides some query logs perhaps, their initial searches would leave no trace and inconvenience nobody.

It'd be better that if someone wants to verify an address isn't already used, he tries to sign up with it. Doing that would expose at least the IP address he's using to sign up and the data he's using to sign up posing as a bona fide customer (i.e., to all intents and purposes, impersonating one). Then if the one signing up wasn't a bona fide customer, surely after a few attempts to guess others' email addresses he'll start to leave a trail, which could allow Paypal to spot him and stop him.

There's no lawful reason to try and guess the Paypal status of email addresses that belong to perfect strangers. And if they're not strangers to you and you got good reason, you could contact them and ask them, whether they've got a Paypal account.

So what is going on here?

Comment: i see, i have an app that allows donations from one paypal account to another, where users can set up different wallets to receive them. On first login by default users sees a form that is filled with the email he provided when registering so that he doesnt have to type it again but he is allowed to change it. I guess i have to remove that option for paypal as i dont want the user to confirm that when he doesnt have active paypal account